My first cryptic crossword
Had a crack at creating a 12x12 cryptic crossword after beginning to love them.
Any comments / suggestions / tips / feedback are greatly appreciated! Enjoy!
Across
1. I came after your plant [5]
3. Loud as a bee [4]
6. Perhaps ask mentor Qui? [8, 4]
8. Pests posts penetrated by Greek character [6]
10. Innocent sample of vegan gelatine [5]
12. Consequently, A&E only half good [4]
15. Booty over the phone for a music maker [4]
18. Fib inside an outsider [5]
20. Black and white kind of star system [6]
21. Inside every computer, a nerd snoozes uncontrollably [4, 3, 5]
23. St Anne initially asked why not go out [4]
24. Celestial traveller to approach small part of Earth [5]
Down
1. Mole burrows into upward burst for defeats [6]
2. Part of your face gives an affirmation [3]
3. Garbage compiler takes first of 20 before capture [3-3]
4. Some crass language! [5]
5. Talent using pan but unearthed life is axed [5]
7. Cutout for bug without vision, say [5]
9. Bridle path, reportedly without a landmass [4]
11. Back and forth time [4]
13. Even trees build a new opportunity [5]
14. General born mostly for African country [5]
16. Unsuspecting airstrip crash [6]
17. Potential test for fish eating you [6]
19. Foolish line Ptolemy kept secret [5]
22. Tree stowed in hat [3]

https://amuselabs.com/pmm/crossword?id=42e41f31&set=72c01470608f3ad24b06049213cc61d9d8ff3f98c0307e7a55f82026167dbb82

Is there a problem with the clue numbering? 10 ac doesn't fit, and on the link it's 21 ac. The clues here seem to be numbered sequentially, as opposed to their location in the grid. For example, there is no 2 ac or 4 ac in the grid.

@WeatherVane That edit should fix it. Markup tends to automate a numeric list from #1 upon seeing the "1." in a list of clues.

@Stiv Ah thanks for the edit, yes I didn't check the numbering, my bad!

This was a fun solve! Thanks for sharing!

Solved:

 

Across:

 1. I came after your plant (5) THY+ME. This was a really nice clue! It stumped me for a while.


 3. Loud as a bee (4) BUSY DDEF? I don't really like BUSY being a synonym for LOUD - I understand BUSY can imply a place that's noisy, but that's usually because the place/area is full of activity - like a busy street is a street that's full of cars, and cars make a lot of noise. Also, not sure if BUSY being the definition for "as a bee", since "as a bee" =/= "busy".


 6. Perhaps ask mentor Qui? (8, 4): QUESTION MARK*. This was a nice clue. The "?" being the definition was funny, even if it's something I think I've seen once or twice.


 8. Pests posts penetrated by Greek character (6) A(PHI)DS. This one was the last one I solved - even though I knew the parsing instructions for it, I couldn't figure it out until I had three letters. I'm not sure how POSTS = ADS, but overall nice clue.


 10. Innocent sample of vegan gelatine (5) _AN+GEL. Okay, so I'm not a big fan of "sample of vegan" being "AN" - sample only really indicates that you should take a part of vegan, but it doesn't specify where. This is something that also happens a lot in this crossword. Maybe other people will disagree with me, but I'm not a huge fan.


 12. Consequently, A&E only half good [4] ER (emergency room) +GO_. I don't think the grammar for the parsing really works - "half good" isn't the same thing as "half of good". If anything, the clue more so reads as half of A&E. Again, someone else might disagree, but a feedback that Deusovi (a mod here, and a phenomenal puzzler in general) gave me a LONG time ago when I first tried to write cryptic clues is that "cryptic grammar is the same as normal english grammar - the trick is re-interpreting words to mean things they don't usually mean, and interpreting other words as the string of letters that makes them up". They went onto say that "'start something' cannot be interpreted to mean "the start of SOMETHING". I think something similar applies here, though I could be wrong.


 15. Booty over the phone for a music maker (4) LUTE (LOOT homophone). I don't really like the definition being "for a music maker" - a lute is an instrument for a music maker, "for a music maker" doesn't necessarily mean a lute. Unless the definition is "a music maker", which in that case is admittedly a clever definition (I was originally thinking that lute was supposed to be a synonym of like bard, but an instrument is also a music maker), but that means that for is a splitter, which has its own issues.


 18. Fib inside an outsider (5) A(LIE)N. Solid clue, though a little weird of a surface.


 20. Black and white kind of star system (6) BINARY ddef. Good double definition, black and white being BINARY is a little eh, but I think it's fine.


 21. Inside every computer, a nerd snoozes uncontrollably (4, 3, 5) ONES AND ZEROS* Nice clue. I think a better surface could be "a nerd snoozes uncontrollably inside every computer" since now the "inside" can also be a red herring as an insertion indicator. I think it would've also been fun to experiment with something like "21 is a kind of star system."


 23. St Anne initially asked why not go out (4) ST+A+Y? Not sure if initially is cluing Anne or ASKED, and parsing is weird. Oh I see, ASKED WHY is Y (like in text messages). I personally think that Y is a fine substitute abbreviation of WHY. Only thing is that if ASKED is being a homophone indicator, I'm not exactly sure if that works. Maybe it does.


 24. Celestial traveller to approach small part of Earth (5) COME+T? Not sure the parsing. If it's an extraction clue (take t, which is a small part of Earth), I don't really think that's a valid way of getting an extraction.

Down:

 1. Mole burrows into upward burst for defeats (6) TRU(+M)PS< (m as in a mole in chemistry, inside SPURT). So there's unfortunate a good number of things that don't really work for me in this clue. The standard abbreviation for mole is mol - I don't think we use m for mole, since there's A LOT of other things in chemistry that use m (m is meter in SI units, M is molarity, m is molality, fancy capital M is molar mass). Also, this comes up in other clues as well - I don't know if "for" works well as a splitter. Quoting Deusovi once again, "the split should tell you how the two parts are related". For doesn't really do that. Finally "defeats" is a bit weird in terms of the grammar of the surface, although is necessary due to the parts of speech.


 2. Part of your face gives an affirmation [3] e(YES)? What I suspect is happening in this clue is that "part of" is performing a double duty of a sort - it's both part of the wordplay definition "part of your face" while also being being an indicator (part of your face gives like gives out?). In my opinion though, words shouldn't really be playing double duty like that, it makes the clue ambiguous. I'm going to assume "an affirmation" is the definition.


 3. Garbage compiler takes first of 20 before capture [3-3] BIN(-ary)BAG Overall good clue. Would've preferred something like "half of 20", but it's good. I'm a little confused on why it was 3-3 instead of 3,3, unless it's typically spelled bin-bag?


 4. Some crass language! (5) _slang_ A nice &lit, though I don't know how some clues a hidden word indicator. Maybe "some of" would be okay, though some of "crass language" as an extraction clue seems a bit odd.


 5. Talent using pan but unearthed life is axed (5) SKILL(-et) Not sure what "using" is doing - it doesn't really work as a split. Also I don't really think "unearthed life" = ET. Unearthly life would make more sense, but unearthed life usually implies something that's hidden that's found, and more directly usually involves digging.


 7. Cutout for bug without vision, say (5) INSE(-c)T. So I'm not a fan of vision--> see --> c. First off, see is a verb, vision is a noun. Fundamentally, they are not synonyms of each other. Now a matter of personal opinion, I think if you're going to use a homophone as a section of the wordplay, rather than the entire wordplay, the words themselves should be the homophones, not a synonym of the word. Otherwise you run into a game of "guess what I am thinking" and strikes me as unfair.


 9. Bridle path, reportedly without a landmass (4) ISLE? @bcz for the parsing, BRIDLE PATH --> BRIDAL PATH --> (a-)ISLE. Yikes. I don't think that's a fair clue - at the very least it should then be bridle (homophone indicator) path without a landmass. The issue here is that the homophone is very ambiguous. PATH is already a close enough synonym of AISLE that you can pretty much get away with PATH, or if you really wanted to, BRIDAL PATH (homophone) landmass. Or bridal path without a landmass.


 11. Back and forth time (4) NOON (palindrome). Nice and straightforward.


 13. Even trees build a new opportunity (5) _R_E_B_I_D I liked this clue a lot! Good surface.


 14. General born mostly for African country (5) GA+BO(-r)N? We have the same issue of "for" being used as a split, and also "mostly" being an ambiguous indicator for "take out a few letters". I've most often seen "mostly" as like a last letter deleter, so like "BORN mostly" would be BOR or "most of BORN" would be BOR. It's not terrible, but it's just not terribly clear. Also GA=General? Would need an explanation on that.


 16. Unsuspecting airstrip crash [6] UNWARY*, anagram of RUNWAY*. Yikes. The cardinal sin of Ximenean cryptic crosswords. It's considered unfair to have indirect anagrams, since a lot of the time it devolves into "guess what word I'm thinking of". Keep anagrams to only letters in your clue.


 17. Potential test for fish eating you (6) TR(+Y)OUT. Aside from for being used as a split, FISH EATING YOU is a bit ambiguous. I don't think Y is a typical abbreviation of YOU, and TRT isn't a fish. So either it's TR(YOU)T or TR(Y)OUT, neither of which fully make sense. A really simple way to fix this surface would've been something like "A fish eating your head is a potential test." or Potential test: Fish eating your head" (I'm sure someone else can come up with an even smoother surface).


 19. Foolish line Ptolemy kept secret (5) _INEPT_ This was one of my favorite clues, very clever. For an even better surface, maybe "Crude line Ptolemy kept secret"?


 22. Tree stowed in hat (3) h(ELM)et? Although it's clever, I don't think this follows the traditional rules of cryptic clues, since definition and wordplay should be separate except for &lits.

I will admit, I'm a bit newer(ish) to cryptic clue solving, so some of these might not be all that bad. I (and I think most of the users of this site) are fairly Ximenean when it comes to cryptic crossword constructions, so that also influences a lot of how we construct CCs on this site.
Just don't do indirect anagrams. Please :)

Perfect, and all your suspected parses are pretty much correct, I'll give some clarifications in the morning.

For 9D, (rot13) gur cnefvat vf "NVFYR", nf va gur cngujnl gung n oevqr gnxrf gb gur nygne va n jrqqvat prerzbal, zvahf "N".

10A: (rot13) NATRY - vg'f n uvqqra jbeq va irtna tryngvar, urapr gnxvat n fnzcyr bs vg.
23A: (rot13) FGNL - guvf bar jnf n yvggyr jrveq naq v'z abg fher vs vg jbexf, ohg gnxr gur vavgvnyf bs Fnvag Naar (FG + N) naq gura nqq n ubzbcubar sbe jul (L).
24A: (rot13) PBZRG - gb nccebnpu (PBZR) + n fznyy cneg bs "Rnegu" (G).
9D: (rot13) VFYR - Lrf guvf jnf n zrna bar, v jnagrq gb gbl jvgu gur snpg gung "oevqyr cngu" fbhaqf yvxr "oevqny cngu", ohg v fhccbfr gung'f whfg n "oevqyr" naq "oevqny" ubzbcubar.
16D: I'll admit I got a bit homophone trigger-happy on this one.

Is there a better bank of terms commonly used in clues? I've been using this https://cryptics.fandom.com/wiki/Cryptipedia, which includes "for" as a linking word which you seem to dislike.

Not sure of a definitive place, typically when I’n looking for any sort of indicators I scour a couple websites to see if I like them. I’ve come to think of them less as a specific group or list, and more about like “does indicator  actually indicate what I want it to do”.  I’d recommend this post though, it’s kind of my go to source.

I don’t think using “for” as a splitter is the worst thing in the world, I just personally don’t like it because I don’t really think it adequately shows the relationship between the wordplay and the definition. In my mind splitters tend to be things that either is showing equivalency or else something that leads or is bridging the wordplay. Britannica does list for as a preposition that can show direction (I’m headed for the store) but I don’t really see that as something that’s bridging the two parts together. I’m sure there are people that will disagree though and that’s okay!

For 10a, that makes more sense, not sure how I missed that. Hidden word indicators/extractions usually either indicate something being concealed or discovered, but I think what you have is okay. For

3A: Busy and loud both describe something with overwhelming detail or colour (a busy/loud painting or a busy/loud shirt).

Ah, okay, that makes sense
